# Identify VKORG field (Sales organization) in a sales order or invoice

Tags: abap, sap-erp, sap-r3

I'm working in an organization where a client can have different sales organizations (VKORG) simultaneously.

As I'd like to analyze data by VKORG cross-client, I'd like to ask if when a sales order is created, VKORG will automatically associated to it? And in what table can I find it?

Or is VKORG associated to the invoice? And in this case how can I join tables to navigate from Sales order to Sales invoice and obtain the VKORG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VKORG is stored on the sales order header table, VBAK.  I believe that is a required field to save the order.